# R: Change the width of the bars in the bar chart using plot_ly()

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

I am having a dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(quarter = c(
  "Q1 2019",
  "Q2 2019", "Q3 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q1 2020", "Q2 2020"
), average = c(
  309L,
  279L, 284L, 246L, 232L, 235L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -6L
))
```

And I am trying to plot a bar chart using `plot_ly()`.

```
 plot_ly(df, x = df$quarter, y=df$average,type = 'bar',
        marker = list(color = "#d3b348"), 
        text = df$average, textposition = 'outside',hoverinfo = 'text')%>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor= 'white'))
```

I am unable to change the width of each bar. I need a thin bar and when I pass `width` argument, the width doesn't gets changed.

How can I set the width of the bars using plot_ly() in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get thin bars via the `layout` argument `bargap`. Try this:

```
plot_ly(df,
  x = df$quarter, y = df$average, type = "bar",
  marker = list(color = "#d3b348"),
  text = df$average, textposition = "outside", hoverinfo = "text"
) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE, hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), bargap = 0.8)
```

And a second approach would be to add the bars via `add_bars(width = 0.2)` (Weird that this works ...):

```
plot_ly(df,
        x = df$quarter, y = df$average,
        marker = list(color = "#d3b348"),
        text = df$average, textposition = "outside", hoverinfo = "text"
) %>%
  add_bars(width = .2) %>% 
  layout(showlegend = FALSE, hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `width` argument in `add_bars`. You have to set the width of each individual bar:

```
plot_ly(df) %>% add_bars(x = ~quarter, y=~average, type = 'bar', 
        width = c(.1,.1,.1,.2,.2,.2),
        marker = list(color = "#d3b348"), 
        text = ~average, textposition = 'outside', hoverinfo = 'text')%>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE, hoverlabel = list(bgcolor= 'white'))
```